# Is $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_{i}}}$ a consistent estimator for $\mu$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, I want to find out if $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{X_{i}}}$$ is a consistent estimator for $\mu$, or not. It's easy to show, using $LLN$, that $\overline{X}$ is a consistent estimator for $\mu$, and I figure I'm supposed do some manipulation to turn this into that, but so far I haven't been able to do so.

How do I proceed?

Comment: What makes you think this might be a consistent estimator?

Comment: Was it assumed that $\mu\ne0\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: No, this was not assumed. Looking over the question again, it asks *whether* this is a consistent estimator... so it might not be

Comment: If this is a theoretical problem, then you need to make sure you values $X_i$ near $0$ occur with very small probability. If this is a practical problem, you need to make sure the harmonic mean is really what you want. (There are some legitimate applications, but few and far between). Also make sure that the $X_i$ can only be positive. In particular, if data are normal, you need to make sure $\mu > 4\sigma$, so that values 0 and below occur with negligible probability.